# Custom UIView won't take up entire screen width as should

Tags: swift, uiview, storyboard, custom-button

I've been cracking my head around this for days now and can't find what the issue is -.-

I have a `MainActionButton` which is a `custom UIView` that I created. These are the constraints I defined to it:

[[image]]

I need it to appear twice on the page as a signup and login buttons, one under the other. This is how it is **supposed to look**:

[image: desired look of the two custom IUView]

First problem I encountered was that for some reason, unless I put each button inside a StackView of its own - they refuse to be placed where I tell them to. Only inside stackViews they obey to stand at the bottom of the screen.

Current issue - even though the stackView is define to be aligned to the sides of the screen (with 20 margin each side) the **custom UIView insist not to take on the full width** as they should!
This is what it looks like:

[image: current look of the two custom UIViews]

- My code of the custom ui is super generic:

```
protocol MainActionButtonDelegate {
    func actionButtonDidPress(btnText: String)
}

class MainActionButtonView: UIView {
    
    @IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var entireButton: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonIcon: UIImageView!
    
    var delegate: MainActionButtonDelegate?
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        commonInit()
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        self.frame = self.bounds
    }
    
    func commonInit() {
        Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("MainActionButtonView", owner: self, options: nil)
        addSubview(contentView)
        contentView.layer.cornerRadius = contentView.frame.size.height / 2
        contentView.clipsToBounds = true
        
        setGestureRecognizer()
    }
    
    func setGestureRecognizer() {
        contentView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: contentView, action: #selector(buttonTapped)))
        contentView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(buttonTapped(tapGestureRecognizer:)))
        contentView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
    }
    
    @objc func buttonTapped(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        delegate?.actionButtonDidPress(btnText: buttonLabel.text!)
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I solve this? Going insane here!

P.S I am using the storyboard

I tried adding different constraints programmatically on the viewDidLoad of the screen's ViewController, but nothing seems to work for me.

Example of my latest attempt:

```
topButton.contentView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: CGFloat(UIScreen.main.bounds.width)).isActive = true
```

Edit #1: This is what it looks like in the hierarchy diagram of the screen:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fz7KC.png)
I can see that my StackView (that I was forced to add to be able to place the button) is indeed the width of the screen, but then the View of the custom UIView doesn't get the same width (even though inside its swift file I constrained it to align to the leading and trailing of the superview)

Comment: Try using the "Debug View Hierarchy" button to see if you can spot any errors

Comment: I edited my post at the bottom and added a screenshot and an explanation. This confirms my suspiscion that the issue is somewhere inside the custom UIView but I still don't understand what is wrong with my constraints that causes this   @Rengers

Comment: This line: `self.frame = self.bounds` in `layoutSubviews()` looks very wrong. What do you get if you remove it?